# Jquery on() method passing args to debounce

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm attempting to grab an input on key up and then debounce it before making a web request with it's value.

```
  $('#list).on('keyup', 'input', this, _.debounce(function(html){ 
                                                   alert(html.value); },200));
```

The problem that I'm running into here is that the argument `html` isn't the input. When I `console.log` it, it says `object object` and when I attempt to `JSON.stringify` it to see what it is, it won't work. It just fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to the event handler should be the event object. If you want to get the value in the list you should be able to use `this.value` or `e.target.value` where `e` is the first argument to the method.